# Node.js + MySQL doesn't get results or respond to Console.log

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am new to Node.js.
I wrote this code:

```
db.query("SELECT * FROM messages", function (error, results, fields){
    if(error){
        console.log("test");
    }
    if(results.length > 0) {
        console.log(results);
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work, it doesn't print anything to console.
Running on Linux.

Comment: how does your database look like

Comment: Any error? If not, then does DB contains any entry?

Comment: table name: messages
rows: id, user_id, time, message.

yes db contains entries. no errors thrown.

I am not sure how to check node.js logs

Comment: If no errors are thrown and no response is given, it looks as if there are no rows in that table.

Comment: there definetely is.

Comment: IT's a chat application, it must load previous messages in chat, so whenever new message it added it goes straight into database

Comment: The code you gave us looks absolutely OK. To verify there are results, just run the same mysql query from your shell and see what it returns.

Comment: Sorry but how is that done? I am new to linux

Comment: Granted you are on the same machine where your mysql is, the command like will look like (edit the USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE): `mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD DATABASE` then it shall tell you that you're connected, do the next: `SELECT * FROM messages;`, do not forget the `;`.

Comment: works fine, it returns results.

Answer (score 0):

For your particular question, do not put your results in an `if` statement yet. Do this instead, just to see what you're working with:

```
console.log( results.toString() );
console.log( JSON.stringify( results ) ); //sometimes this throws errors, if the object is complex
```

That should let you see what you're working with. If `reulsts` isn't an array, it won't have a `.length` attribute, and you won't reach the `console.log`.

However...

I'm always pushing [KnexJS](http://knexjs.org/) when I see raw MySQL statements in Node code. Knex handles two common things for you, db connections and connection pools, plus makes writing dynamic queries a breeze. (as in, you don't have to manipulate SQL strings...)

Install knex `npm install knex --save`

In your app or environment setup

```
var Knex = require('knex');
Knex.knex = Knex({...}); //set options for DB
```

In other files, reference the instance like this:

```
var knex = require('knex).knex;
```

So your query could look like this:

```
var query = knex('messages').select();
console.log('About to perform query: ' + query.toString() );
query.exec( function( err, results ){
    if(error){
        console.log("test");
    }
    console.log(results);
    //do other things here, like callback(results);
} );
```

Good luck!

Comment: I tried console.log( results.toString() );
console.log( JSON.stringify( results ) );

It just doesn't show anything in console whatsoever. 
I assume thats suppsoed to show up in Chrome inspect element console?

Comment: Holy crap, it was working all along. I just though that console.log() outputs to chrome console. 
I am running forever module to make sure my node.js chat server always runs so it didnt print anything to console. 

Any tips how can I monitor outputs? perhaps there is a way to make a log file which will log everything?

Comment: Two popular logging frameworks are [bunyan](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan) and [winston](https://github.com/flatiron/winston). There are probably others. These can be configured to log to a file or a stream (or both!). "Monitoring outputs" would probably programatic, as in you would catch the error or problem before it hits the log.